# Executing an .HTML in a web-browser - node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm running a program that validates a `.html` file (`index.html`) and then runs the program on a web-browser. `(localhost:port/index.html)`.

My program understands that I'm asking for the right file but I can't execute the `.html` file in web-browser (just trying to display the date).

I've been looking online for references but maybe I'm not looking in the right direction or I'm just overlooking something.

Also the response.end doesn't print onto the web-browser even though other functions with response.end it works perfectly.

```
function doHTML(http_request, response)
{
    // Read the requested file content from file system
    fs.readFile('MYHTML/' + http_request, function (err, data) {
    console.log('Hey youre in the HTML function');
    response.end('Hey you got it working');

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to NodeJS as well, but I believe the following link may help you out:

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render

Also, I believe response.end('..text and stuff..') would send the text to your web/desktop client, so that you can process the response there: print it, parse it etc. So it's understandable to me that response.end wouldn't directly print onto the web-browser as console.log would do.

Hope this helps.

Edit: Just realizing that my response assumes you're using the Express framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your function as a request handler for node.js it looks like you should use `http_request.url` instead of `http_request`. The following function worked for me (server skeleton from [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/your-first-node-js-http-server/)):

```
const fs = require('fs')
const http = require('http')  
const port = 3000

const requestHandler = (http_request, response) => {  
  console.log(http_request.url)
  fs.readFile('MYHTML/' + http_request.url, function (err, data) {
    if (! err){
      console.log('Hey youre in the HTML function.');
      response.write(data);
      response.write('Hey you got it working');
      response.end();
    } else {
        response.end("File not found.");
    }
  });
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)

server.listen(port, (err) => {  
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```